# Using JavaScript to create a custom play/pause button for audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<audio id="broadcast" preload='auto'>
    <source src='broadcastThoughts.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>
<a href="#" id="control"><img src='play.png' style='height:10vh; width:auto;'></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
if ($.cookie("sound") == "off") {
    $("#broadcast").get(0).volume = 0;
}
else {
    $("#broadcast").get(0).volume = .05;
}

var yourAudio = document.getElementById('broadcast'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('control'),
    playHTML = "<img src='play.png' style='height:10vh; width:auto;'>",
    pauseHTML = "<img src='pause.png' style='height:10vh; width:auto;'>";


ctrl.onclick = function () {

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === pauseHTML;
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? playHTML : pauseHTML;

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
```

Yup. Seems simple enough, but some reason this code will only play the audio and change the image to the "pause" button. After that, clicking the pause button won't change it back to play or pause the audio. I think the problem might have something to do with this,

```
// Update the Button
var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === pauseHTML;
ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? playHTML : pauseHTML;
```

, since this same code works fine if the only HTML you are adding to the "ctrl" element is text (ie. "Play!" and "Pause!" rather than images).

Any tips? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are better off using a Boolean value instead of checking html since the browser can CHANGE the html.

Comment: Could you make it a background-image instead and just add/remove a class with different background-image properties?

Comment: I changed the "ctrl.onclick" to:

    ctrl.onclick = function () {
    
        // Update the Button
        ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? playHTML : pauseHTML;
    
        // Update the Audio
        var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
        yourAudio[method]();
        
        pause = !pause;
    
        // Prevent Default Action
        return false;
    };

, which solved the problem. Thanks epascarello!

Comment: Sorry that ^^^^ looks so terrible, but I'm not allowed to answer the question for 8 hours! THE PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED

Comment: Why you mix jQuery and its DOM equivalents? Be consistent and use jQuery everywhere)